# How to make rattan ball?

Tags: mesh

I'm new here.
Anyone know how to make rattan ball like this?
https://www.google.com/search?q=takraw+ball+3d+model&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR0NPE9sXgAhWMXSsKHbQ8C_0Q_AUIDigB&biw=1440&bih=757#imgrc=hJRjAIPy0H21GM:

UPDATE :
I have progress.
[image]

UPDATE :
Its kinda solved. I dont know how to make it the right way, but its done. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can use the Tissue addon. Read: [Add repeating pattern to surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87384/add-repeating-pattern-to-surface/87460#874600)

Comment: or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131481/fill-in-objects-surface-with-another-object/131483#131483 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105508/making-holes-in-an-object-using-an-image-as-a-reference/105535#105535

Comment: or: [How can I create spherical topology from a 2D image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56919/how-can-i-create-spherical-topology-from-a-2d-image/56924#56924)

Comment: so please explain, I'm curious to know how you succeeded  ;)

Comment: @blackcats54 Instead of adding an image of the solution in the question, please write an answer detailing what you did. That way others that have a similar question can learn from your experience.